# response.headers.get('Set-Cookies') returning null in the browser environment but giving value in the node environment

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies, fetch-api

I am login the linkedIn through the code and then trying to use jsession id for the further use.but response.headers.get('Set-Cookies') returning null in the browser environment but giving value in the node environment.

```
(async () => {
    const loginPageResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/home');
    const loginPageHtml = await loginPageResponse.text();
    const loginCsrfParamMatches = loginPageHtml.match(/name="loginCsrfParam" value="([^"]+)"/);
    const loginCsrfParam = loginCsrfParamMatches && loginCsrfParamMatches[1];
  
    const loginFormData = new URLSearchParams();
    loginFormData.append('session_key', 'username');
    loginFormData.append('session_password', 'password');
    loginFormData.append('loginCsrfParam', loginCsrfParam);
    
  
    const loginResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: loginFormData,
      credentials:"include",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Referer': 'https://www.linkedin.com/login',
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
      },
      redirect: 'manual'
    });
    const jsessionId = loginResponse.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
    console.log(jsessionId);
    const jId = jsessionId.match(/ajax:\d+/)[0];
    console.log(jId);
  
  
    const companyResponse = await fetch("api_endpoints"+"company_name",{
      method: 'GET',
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "csrf-token": jId,
            
         }
    })
    
  })();
```

Comment: Per-spec, browsers are required to block frontend code from accessing the value of the Set-Cookie response header. Browsers filter out the Set-Cookie header when processing responses. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-forbidden-response-header-name%E2%91%A0.

Comment: You will need to use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived to get such forbidden headers.

Comment: is there any other to achieve what I am trying to do with fetch api. I am login the linkedIn and trying to jsession id for the further use-@wOxxOm